# Why does the pods hostname don't resolve?

Tags: kubernetes, service, hostname

i have a problem with pods in kubernetes.
i have an app pod (invoice)  with init container that checks if mysql pod (invoice-mysql) is running
invoice-mysql is running and ready but the init container in the invoice pod is not seeing it

here is the logs of the init container

```
DB is not yet reachable;sleep for 10s before retry
DB is not yet reachable;sleep for 10s before retry
nc: bad address 'invoice-mysql'
nc: bad address 'invoice-mysql'
DB is not yet reachable;sleep for 10s before retry
nc: bad address 'invoice-mysql'
DB is not yet reachable;sleep for 10s before retry
nc: bad address 'invoice-mysql'
```

here is the yaml of invoice

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: invoice
  namespace: jhipster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: invoice
      version: 'v1'
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: invoice
        version: 'v1'
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - invoice
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 100
      initContainers:
        - name: init-ds
          image: busybox:latest
          command:
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-c'
            - |
              while true
              do
                rt=$(nc -z -w 1 invoice-mysql 3306)
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                  echo "DB is UP"
                  break
                fi
                echo "DB is not yet reachable;sleep for 10s before retry"
                sleep 10
              done
      containers:
        - name: invoice-app
          image: docker.pkg.github.com/morsi84/kubernetes/invoice
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: prod
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI
              value: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry.Jhipster.svc.cluster.local:8761/config
            - name: JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: registry-secret
                  key: registry-admin-password
            - name: EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE
              value: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry.Jhipster.svc.cluster.local:8761/eureka/
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:mysql://invoice-mysql.Jhipster.svc.cluster.local:3306/invoice?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
            - name: SPRING_SLEUTH_PROPAGATION_KEYS
              value: 'x-request-id,x-ot-span-context'
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: ' -Xmx256m -Xms256m'
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '512Mi'
              cpu: '500m'
            limits:
              memory: '1Gi'
              cpu: '1'
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8081
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /management/health
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 15
            failureThreshold: 6
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /management/health
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
      imagePullSecrets:
          - name: regcred
```

here is the yaml of invoice-mysql

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: invoice-mysql
  namespace: jhipster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: invoice-mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: invoice-mysql
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:8.0.20
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              value: root
            - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
              value: 'yes'
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: invoice
          args:
            - --lower_case_table_names=1
            - --skip-ssl
            - --character_set_server=utf8mb4
            - --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql/
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '512Mi'
              cpu: '500m'
            limits:
              memory: '1Gi'
              cpu: '1'
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: invoice-mysql
  namespace: jhipster
spec:
  selector:
    app: invoice-mysql
  ports:
    - port: 3306
```

here is a description of the invoice-mysql service

```
Name:              invoice-mysql
Namespace:         jhipster
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=invoice-mysql
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.98.220.110
Port:              <unset>  3306/TCP
TargetPort:        3306/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.66:3306
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

working environment:
[image: working environment]

faulty environment:
[image: faulty environment]

Can you help me please

Answer (score 1):

The problem in fact was due to the firwall on my centos hosts, i disabled the firewall and the names started resolving.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a full service domain instead of `invoice-mysql`. Can you try using `invoice-mysql.Jhipster.svc.cluster.local` instead?

Comment: Hello Syam, that name doesn't resolve either, i have attached screenshots in my question showing the nslookup on a faulty enironment and the result in a working environment

Comment: I found this error in the dns logs
i executed this command: kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
and i got this output:
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6473717310687983585.3306693132410931183. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:39609->10.66.15.254:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6473717310687983585.3306693132410931183. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:55906->10.66.15.254:53: read: no route to host

Comment: Is it a newly built cluster? Is there any other services' DNS resolution works fine on the same cluster?
If its a newly built environment, better to compare from bottom up, with the working environment.